# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, xsd

Every time build failed and show error

1. could not find the document;
2. the document could not be read;
3. the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

How can I solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.3.xsd
">
```

Comment: Please put yourself into the position of someone that reads your text. If you don't put more effort into describing the exact problem within its context, no one will be interested to put effort into helping you, either.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the STS for every time build you must be online.
The best solution is to use java based configuration.